# how i call method of button from viewdidload

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have 10 `UIButton` objects. I define a single action for all of them. I want to animate the `UIScrollView` to a desired image location when I on the related button. I have implemented this project using storyboards and I have one method for all 10 buttons. I gave a tag to each button in `viewDidLoad` in `viewcontroller.m` file like this

```
button1.tag = 10;
button1.tag = 11;
button1.tag = 12;
button1.tag = 13;
button1.tag = 14;
button1.tag = 15;
button1.tag = 16;
button1.tag = 17;
button1.tag = 18;
button1.tag = 19;
```

// viewcontroller.m file

```
-(IBAction) Button1:(id) sender
{

 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextView" sender:sender];
}
```

This button method will take me to nextviewcontroller and its working fine, but in `nextviewctontroller.m` file i want to animate my `UIScrollView` to desired location. I am doing it like this in `nextviewcontroller.m` file, but its not working.

```
viewDidload
{
if ([sender tag] == 10)
{
[yourScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100) animated:YES];
}
else if ([sender tag] == 11)
{
[yourScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320,0,100,100) animated:YES];
}
/*
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
and its continue to the last tag 
*/

}
```

It does not animate the `UIScrollView` to the desired location and one thing remember here I have declared `sender` as type `id` in header file. Kindly tell me how I can animate `UIScrollView` to the desired location when I click on corresponding button. I also wanted to say I did not copy and paste this code from my xcode project. I wrote this code just give you idea what I want.

Comment: How are you getting to the next view?  Navigation controller?  Segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the header of the next view controller add this

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *buttonBeingPassedIn;
```

In the first View controller you want to create a UIButton globally so you can access it in any method in that file, call it something like: buttonThatWasTapped.  Then you can do something like this:

```
-(IBAction) Button1:(id) sender
{
    buttonBeingPassedIn = (UIButton *)sender;
    // Notice this has been changed to sender: self
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextView" sender:self];
}
```

In the first view controller you need to add this method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
      nextViewController *vc = (nextViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
      vc.buttonBeingPassedIn = buttonThatWasTapped;
}
```

Then you will be able to do

```
viewDidload
{
    if (buttonBeingPassedIn == 10)
}
```

Comment: but why you implement this method - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender  i cam successfully move from one view controller to another on button click

Comment: and second thing is that you've declare property for buttonBeingPassedIn  in nextview controller how you directly access it in the button1 method of first view controller

Comment: Thats what the prepare for segue is for, you say vc.button to access the property and set it to the button that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, you are in your second viewController and no longer have access to the tags on your buttons.  They are out of scope at that point unless you have a reference to the first view controller (which you shouldn't).

You should create a tag or offset property on your "nextViewController".  Then, depending on how you get there from the first view controller, you need to have the first view controller set that property on the second.  Then you can access it in your second.  If you are using segue you should do this in the prepareForSegue method of the first view controller.

If you are pushing it on a navigation controller, you would set that property after allocating the second view controller and before pushing it onto the navigation stack.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad. You shouldn't put geometry-related stuff in viewDidLoad as the view's geometry (frame etc) is not set at that point.

Comment: His second view controller does not have access to anything named sender since sender is only in the scope of the method in the first view controller.